# Google webmasters v3 API reporting incorrect status for sitemap whereas Search Console correctly shows it as "pending"

Tags: google-search-console, google-api

When I go to the search console site and go to `Crawl` -> `Sitemaps`

```
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitemap-list?hl=en&authuser=0&siteUrl=myURL.com
```

I see the table with 1 entry `/sitemap.xml` and 45 submitted, no data about indexed and the `indexed` column says `Pending`.

However a call against the `webmasters v3` api for this sitemap returns 45 submitted, 0 indexed and pending = false.

That last bit is giving me a lot of trouble in our automated error reporting since the sitemap is clearly not done processing (indexed is normally between 43 and 45) but the cron job that looks at the API flags an alert with 0 indexed.

Has anyone encountered this issue and can help out?

EDIT:
I should mention that at some point the search console UI switches from `pending` to giving the actual number of indexed pages. The problem is the API always returning `false` for the `is_pending` property.

[image: screnshot of api vs search console]

Comment: what is the problem, where you want to be helped out? Google isn't quite fast on sitemap eating. i would say: check twice, whether your sitemaps are standard conform, not blocked through robots and contain only canonical urls answering 200. Then wait. Google's tools are distributed on many different datacenters, your data runs and is aggregated through many caches - there i snothing you can do, beside of ensure you provide correct data and wait.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the API to me.   Have you tried reporting it to Google via the product forums?  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters

Comment: I've posted in the product forum but haven't gotten a reply yet. as for @Evgeniy, please read the question carefully. This isn't about the speed of indexing but about the API returning false information (i.e. that the sitemap is "not pending" when it actually is.